how to Create two packages for one product lbs in magento 2.4.5
A customer wants to order a large order, however, when the shipping weight exceeds 50lb. This is likely because the shipping would need to be separated into multiple boxes.
We need the order to be automatedly separated into multiple boxes when the weight exceeds 50lb
If add 10 product quality to the cart, you will not get a shipping rate from UPS. Also, please make the box maximum weight size 49 lb.
